# iOS app adhoc distribution and MDM

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, mdm

We want to develop apps for a variety of separate clients for use on their iPads/iPhones.
Right now we have a developer license and and provision UUIDs manually and distribute the app OTA via a web server.

This limits us to 100 devices per license and leaves us paying for upkeep of the license. 
Some of our clients may also be interested in using an MDM software package.

What is the best way for us to provision and push apps to many clients and more that 100 devices? Would each client need to pay for their own enterprise license?

Any input is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It's actually 100 devices per year that you've been on part of the ADC. For example, when you renew you will get an extra 100 devices. You will have to pay for a new licence either way, if it's in the App store and you stop paying the fee, it gets pulled from the store!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would each client need to pay for
>   their own enterprise license?

It looks like it, according to the terms and conditions available here: http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

More specifically, from [this page](http://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.html):

> *I am a developer who wants to create an in house app for my client.
>   Can I join the iOS Developer
>   Enterprise Program to do that?*
>
> The iOS Developer Enterprise Program should be used to develop and
>   distribute proprietary in-house
>   applications to your own employees
>   within your own company. As such, your
>   company would not qualify for direct
>   Program enrollment in this situation.
>   We would suggest that your client
>   apply for enrollment in the Program,
>   and, once enrolled in the Program,
>   your client may add the appropriate
>   developers from your company to their
>   iOS Development Team.